# "Documents" set to a drive that no longer exists

Tags: windows-8.1, drive-letter, my-documents

After installing Windows 8.1, I set my "Documents" Folder (note, not the *library*, but the item listed under "This PC") to a partitioned drive with letter "T", as I used to have a small partition dedicated to "My Documents" in Win-7.

I later ended up simplifying my drives and merging several partitions. T no longer exists, and the contents of my old "My Documents" is now in a directory on a drive lettered "I".

Now I've notice that under "This PC" instead of "Document" it's just "T:`" (see screenshot). I cannot select this item now, when I left-click, I get this:

[image]

,,,I cannot right-click to get to properties either. I get this:

[image: screen shot of T-drive under "This PC"]

This is proving quite problematic. I couldn't install Acrobat Reader, because (the install error said) it could not locate "T".

I need to point "Documents" to its true location (I:/Documents) How do I get out of this pickle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possibility would be to temporary recreate this drive letter, this should unlock everything, so you can cleanly change your "Documents" folder location.

You can assign a drive letter to a folder using `subst` command in an administrator `cmd` :

```
subst T: I:\Documents
```

Such assignment does not remain after a reboot, so you should correct your "Documents" location to its real location, not keep going with `T:`.

Comment: The command ran fine (as admin). To double-check, I tried it twice and got the message "Drive already SUBSTed". But the display under "This PC" didn't change, and the "T:\" still cannot be selected or right-clicked. Notice (in the screnshots) that it doesn't even list "Documents" under "This PC", just "T:\". Might there be another place from which I can set these collections? (note again, this is different than the *Libraries* where Documents points to the correct location.

Comment: So this was essentially the answer. Though I couldn't get it to work via the admin command, I did happen to have a partition on an HDD which I'd reserved for installing an alternate OS on but hadn't yet, that I could rename to T. With T in existence, I was free to point Documents -- which was still showing as "T:\", even after re-pointing it -- to I:\Documents. It took a reboot for Window explorer to properly show it again as "Documents"

Answer (score 1):

You can try in the Registry. Below is a `.reg` file that runs from our logon server to redirect the Documents folder to their individual Home drives:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders]
"Personal"=hex(2):68,00,3a,00,00,00
```

Otherwise, you can start `regedit`, navigate to **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders**, and change the **Personal** value. This takes effect after you reboot Explorer; either crashing it, killing it in Task Manager, or logging off and logging back in. Be warned though, that the registry code above will map it to the H:\, which may not be what you want.